# Remove repeated values in multi select dropdown using php

Tags: php

I have two foreach loops one contains the event list and one contains the values that have been selected by the user from the database.

**Here is my code:**

```
<select class="form-control select2-select" autocomplete="off" name="event[]" multiple>
<option value="">--Select--</option>
  <?php
  $variable= $editlist['evname'];
  $array = explode(',', $variable);

  foreach($evlist as $list){
  foreach($array as $value){
  ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $list->event ?>"<?php if($list->event==$value) echo "selected";?>><?php echo $list->event ?>
   </option>
   <?php
 }
 }
?>
</select>
```

**$evlist contains:**

```
array:9 [▼
  0 => "3rd Edition Healthscape Summit India-2016"
  1 => "6th Edition RESCOM Summit - Middle East"
  2 => "8th Edition Hotelier Summit Middle East-2016"
  3 => "Smart Education  India-2016"
  4 => "15th Edition Design Mission India-2016"
  5 => "16th Edition Design Mission  Africa-2016"
  6 => "1st Edition India Industrial Summit 2016"
  7 => "Pharmac  India-2016"
  8 => "17th Edition Design Mission Saudi Arabia-2016"
]
```

**here $array contains only two values like:**

```
Array ( 
[0] => Smart Education India-2016 
[1] => 6th Edition RESCOM Summit - Middle East 
)
```

**And my output is as follows:**

[image: output]

how to prevent the repeated values in the dropdown ?

Comment: you can create an array to hold the values that you've already added and then check if the value is in the array.

Comment: But it has only two values which i m getting from the database i have to make them as selected in dropdown .

Comment: He is referring to $list->event. Also you mentioned sql database, use select where event not in [event list]

Comment: Yeah i understood.But both variables are getting from two tables like one table has all event list and another table has  only two values .

Answer (score 1):

There are two options:

1) Make your array unique

```
<select class="form-control select2-select" autocomplete="off" name="event[]" multiple>
<option value="">--Select--</option>
  <?php
  $variable= $editlist['evname'];
  $array = explode(',', $variable);
  foreach(array_unique($evlist)as $list){  ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $list->event ?>"<?php if(in_array($list->event,$array)) echo "selected";?> > <?php echo $list->event ?>
   </option>
   <?php
  }
?>
</select>
```

2) In query add group by option value(i.e. event)

Comment: No it did not work. Actually my $evlist has unique values only  .But its happening because of $array has two values and two times its rotating the foreach loop for that its giving the values are getting repeated two times.

Comment: i have edited my answer,Please try it if it works for you.

Comment: some how i  made it work .now no repeated values but one the first value getting selected ..Second value is not getting selected .any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

please try it :

```
<select class="form-control select2-select" autocomplete="off" name="event[]" multiple>
<option value="">--Select--</option>
  <?php
  $variable= $editlist['evname'];
  $array = explode(',', $variable);

  foreach($evlist as $list){
  ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $list->event ?>"

<?php 
if(in_array($list->event, $array))
echo "selected";?>><?php echo $list->event ?>
   </option>
   <?php
 }
?>
</select>
```

Comment: Yeah, this is working but only the first value is getting selected .how to make both values getting selected  ? any idea ?

Comment: can you debug ?


What is value in $array ?

Comment: Yes $array contains the values as i mentioned in the question .